# Javascript roundoff number to nearest 0.5

Tags: javascript

Can someone give me an idea how can i round off a number to the nearest 0.5.
I have to scale elements in a web page according to screen resolution and for that i can only assign font size in pts to 1, 1.5 or 2 and onwards etc.

If i round off it rounds either to 1 decimal place or none. 
How can i accomplish this job?

Answer (score 260, accepted):

Write your own function that multiplies by 2, rounds, then divides by 2, e.g.

```
function roundHalf(num) {
    return Math.round(num*2)/2;
}
```

Comment: Just used this to clean up a reduce function on monetary values that was coming back with like 9 decimal points... (num*100)/100 worked perfectly.

Comment: If you want to end up with either 13.0 or 13.5, I combined your answer with the one below:

function roundHalf(num) {
  return (Math.round(num*2)/2).toFixed(1);
}

Comment: rounding the num*2 is not working for all case..try any decimal like 15.27 => using your formula will give => 15 where in fact it should have returned 15.5.  **** I think using toFixed will be better (num*2).toFixed()/2

Comment: @sfdxbomb Have you checked this? In my browser's console `roundHalf(15.27)` returns
15.5

Answer (score 116):

Here's a more generic solution that may be useful to you:

```
function round(value, step) {
    step || (step = 1.0);
    var inv = 1.0 / step;
    return Math.round(value * inv) / inv;
}
```

`round(2.74, 0.1)` = 2.7

`round(2.74, 0.25)` = 2.75

`round(2.74, 0.5)` = 2.5

`round(2.74, 1.0)` = 3.0

Comment: What does `inv` mean? What's the `inv` variable represents?

Comment: @Deilan I'd guess `inverse`.

Answer (score 14):

Just a stripped down version of all the above answers:

```java
Math.round(valueToRound / 0.5) * 0.5;
```

Generic:

```java
Math.round(valueToRound / step) * step;
```

Answer (score 5):

To extend the top answer by newtron for rounding on more than only 0.5

```
function roundByNum(num, rounder) {
    var multiplier = 1/(rounder||0.5);
    return Math.round(num*multiplier)/multiplier;
}

console.log(roundByNum(74.67)); //expected output 74.5
console.log(roundByNum(74.67, 0.25)); //expected output 74.75
console.log(roundByNum(74.67, 4)); //expected output 76
```

Answer (score 3):

`Math.round(-0.5)` returns **0**, but it should be **-1** according to the math rules.

More info: [Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)
and [Number.prototype.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```
function round(number) {
    var value = (number * 2).toFixed() / 2;
    return value;
}
```

Comment: @Yuri To expand on what you're saying, `round` rounds to the next integer greater than the given value, which in terms of negative numbers would be towards the positive integer spectrum. -2.5 would go to -2. Is that correct?

Comment: Yup just verified. `Math.ceil(-1.75) == -1` and `Math.floor(-1.75) == -2`. So for anyone getting tripped up by this, just think of it as `ceil` returns a **greater than** number, `floor` returns a **less than** number.

Comment: Rounding -0.5 does equal 0.

Answer (score 2):

These answers weren't useful for me, I wanted to always round to a half (so that drawing with svg or canvas is sharp).

This rounds to the closest .5 (with a bias to go higher if in the middle)

```js
function sharpen(num) {
  const rem = num % 1
  if (rem < 0.5) {
    return Math.ceil(num / 0.5) * 0.5 + 0.5
  } else {
    return Math.floor(num / 0.5) * 0.5
  }
}

console.log(sharpen(1)) // 1.5
console.log(sharpen(1.9)) // 1.5
console.log(sharpen(2)) // 2.5
console.log(sharpen(2.5)) // 2.5
console.log(sharpen(2.6)) // 2.5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var f = 2.6;
var v = Math.floor(f) + ( Math.round( (f - Math.floor(f)) ) ? 0.5 : 0.0 );
```

Comment: if f = 1.9, this will result in v = 1, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function roundToTheHalfDollar(inputValue){
      var percentile = Math.round((Math.round(inputValue*Math.pow(10,2))/Math.pow(10,2)-parseFloat(Math.trunc(inputValue)))*100)
      var outputValue = (0.5 * (percentile >= 25 ? 1 : 0)) + (0.5 * (percentile >= 75 ? 1 : 0))
      return Math.trunc(inputValue) + outputValue
    }
```

I wrote this before seeing Tunaki's better response ;)

Answer (score 0):

As a bit more flexible variation of the good answer above.

```
function roundNumber(value, step = 1.0, type = 'round') {
  step || (step = 1.0);
  const inv = 1.0 / step;
  const mathFunc = 'ceil' === type ? Math.ceil : ('floor' === type ? Math.floor : Math.round);

  return mathFunc(value * inv) / inv;
}
```