# Rounding figures to nearest

Tags: javascript

I was looking for the answer to round after a calculation but I cannot seem to find it. I know you have to use the round code in your javascript but I do not know where to put it, it does not seem to work..

```
      val1 = parseInt($("#figure1").val());
      val2 = parseInt($("#figure2").val());
      $("#totalcost").val( ("$" val1 + val2 ));
```

Where would I put the rounding code, so it rounds the total cost?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [Math.round](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_round.asp):

```
var rounded = Math.round(val1 + val2);
$("#totalcost").val("$" + rounded);
```

Or, when you want to round it on 2 decimals

```
var rounded = Math.round((val1 + val2) * 100) / 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could modify your code to,

```
var val1 = parseFloat($("#figure1").val());
var val2 = parseFloat($("#figure2").val());
$("#totalcost").val( ("$" + Math.round(val1 + val2) ));
```

You can also use the `toFixed` method for rounding to specific decimal points as follows,

**Example**

```
var val1 = parseFloat(1.12521);
var val2 = parseFloat(2.3213123);
var total= ("$" + Math.round(val1 + val2) );
var totalWithTwoDecimals= ("$" + (val1 + val2).toFixed(2) );
console.log(total);//$3
console.log(totalWithTwoDecimals);//$3.45
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a `round` method

```
function round(valToRound) {
// do the rounding
}
```

and use it like this

`var total = round(val1 + val2);`

and then pass `total` to your final statement.

`$("#totalcost").val("$"+ total);`

As for how to actually round, you can [look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453421/how-to-round-float-numbers).

Comment: Math with a capital M?