# how to use JavaScript to calculate the currency

Tags: javascript

hi I actually trying to do calculate the two numbers,, it was working, but now I don't know how to turn the number into currency. so before the number  it need to show £ sign. 
I was researched in Google ,and i tried some things but its not actually working.

```
var name,child,result;

function setvalues()
{
   name=Number(document.getElementById("name").value);
   child=Number(document.getElementById("child").value);
}
```

on that name field user has to enter some number to calculate,, its was calculating but just a number not with an currency sign... I seen some of the JavaScript function to change the currency format but its not very clear... and how to add three vaules together and show in one textbox with £ sign

Comment: The HTML entity is &pound;

Comment: It seems your problem is not calculating the numerical value for the currency, but displaying a well formatted string representation of some currency value.

Comment: var name,child,result;
function setvalues()
{
name=Number(document.getElementById("name").value);
child=Number(document.getElementById("child").value);
}

function sum()
{
 setvalues();
 result= name*child;
 document.getElementById('total').value=result;
} this is actually my code its working fine.. but i am trying to change into currency using javascript

Comment: Use something like: `var total = '£' + result.toFixed(2);`

Comment: where you want me to put that code rob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure of what you are trying to accomplish but I will try to answer as best I can. I would recommend that if you are working with currency(which can be a especially be a pain in JavaScript). I would recommend using a library to handle this for you. I have used accounting.js in the past and it works very well for these sorts of things:

http://josscrowcroft.github.io/accounting.js/

If you update your question with more information I will update my answer.

**UPDATE**

Try this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjIHn/. It should produces the output you are wanting.

Comment: i was using javascript

Comment: sorry i got a probelm now ... it is showing the £ sign but now its showing 0 after the pound sign with the price and other 2 zero..

Comment: Look at the JavaScript code in the box on the top right. I added the pound sign to the beginning of the string that is set as the value of the input. If my answer solves your problem please mark it as accepted.

Comment: What did you provide as input? The result may need to be rounded. See this answer for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453421/how-to-round-float-numbers-in-javascript

Comment: actually it was working showing as a whole number,, but i was trying to add other value... like an third ..input box.. to caculate the total amount plus the third box number,, but its not actually showing the correct vaule... i think i know what is doing.. its just adding numbers like an £ sign .. but its not caculating the price when i add the 3 value

Comment: Yes. '1' + '2' (strings) will result in '12', 1 + 2 (integers) will result in 3. You will need to convert the value of the input field to a number before performing the arithmetic.