# Round Decimal in price

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like to round up to 2 decimal places.

Input:
2.456
2.890

Output:
2.500
2.900

How can I do this in JavaScript?

Comment: i think this can help you, why you dont google it first? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round float numbers in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453421/how-to-round-float-numbers-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Use   `Math.round(num * 100) / 100`

Comment: I believe you want Math.ceil() instead