# Javascript : Rounding 2 decimal places of boundary 0.5

Tags: javascript, decimal, rounding

How to get the rounding number of 0.5, previously I found in this link:

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137986/javascript-roundoff-number-to-nearest-0-5)

But this is not what I want:

I want like this example:

1. 10.24 = 10.25
2. 17.90 = 17.90
3. 3.89 = 3.90
4. 7.63 = 7.65

jQuery will be fine with me.

Comment: Multiply by 20, round, then divide by 20

Comment: Multiple by 20, in fact, then divide by 20.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Math.round(num * 20) / 20`, if you are looking to round a number to nearest `0.05`.

Comment: Great hack with likely minimal operations.

Answer (score 3):

This will do what you need...

```
function roundoff(value) {
    return (Math.round(value / 0.05) * 0.05).toFixed(2);
}
```

Using `Math.round` will round the value to the nearest 0.05, and then using `toFixed(2)` will ensure the result has 2 decimal places, even if they're both zeros.

Here's a working example...

http://jsfiddle.net/xoo7c898/