# Math.floor () to round down to nearest 0.5 in javascript

Tags: javascript, rounding

I have a function from excel that I use: =FLOOR(value,0.5)

With this function, I round DOWN to the nearest half value. For example:

10.55 becomes 10.5
10.99 becomes 10.5
10.2 becomes 10

Etc.

Is there an equivalent in javascript? I know that Math.floor () will round down to the nearest integer. However, does anyone know of a good way to round down to the nearest 0.5 instead?

Thank you in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137986/javascript-roundoff-number-to-nearest-0-5 <-- same basic idea

Comment: `r = Math.floor(v * 2) / 2`?

Comment: I was thinking of a more generic , if all things were perfict

Comment: function eFloor(v, b) { return (Math.floor( v*(1/b) )*b); }

Answer (score 2):

Here's your function:

```js
function slipFloor(num){
  let f = Math.floor(num);
  if(num-f < 0.5){
    return f;
  }
  return f+0.5;
}
console.log(slipFloor(10.55));
console.log(slipFloor(10.99));
console.log(slipFloor(10.2));
```

Comment: This works very well, thank you!