# How to round of value nearest to the integer in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to round off nearest integer after decimal.If the value after decimal above .25 than it should round of .50. It means the result should be 14.50 and if the result 14.25 or under than it should be only 14. Please check examples

```js
document.getElementById("total1").innerHTML =(Math.ceil(501/500)*3.60*2).toFixed(2);

document.getElementById("total2").innerHTML =(Math.ceil(500/500)*3.60*2).toFixed(2);
```

```html
<b>Result 1: (above 25)</b> 
<div id="total1"></div>
<br>
<b>Expected Result 1:</b>
14.50
<br>
<br>

<b>Result 2: (below 25)</b> 
<div id="total2"></div>
<br>
<b>Expected Result 2:</b>
14
<br>
<p>If the value after decimal above .25 than it should round of .50. It means the result should be 14.50 and if the result 14.25 or under than it should be only 14.</p>
```

Comment: Could you please add a few sample inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: @JanStránský added examples, please check.

Comment: @Ivar sorry, I already checked this link but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I meant something **specific** like "14.4 -> 14.50" and a few other **specific** clear examples. E.g. what you have provided: `(Math.ceil(500/500)*3.60*2).toFixed(2)` is 7.20 and you expect 14, why? Another point, is the HTML needed here?

Comment: As @Ivar said this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137986/javascript-roundoff-number-to-nearest-0-5 is exactly your answer

Comment: According to accepted answer, it is duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6138087/2700104)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A faster way of rounding a number also to `+0.5` is by rounding the number multiplied by 2, and then divide the result by 2 as well.

```js
function roundToDecimal(number) {
    return Math.round(number * 2) / 2;
}

console.log(roundToDecimal(14.40));
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! The problem is solved..

Comment: @TahaFarooqui How does it differ from [already proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6138087/2700104)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function to round your numbers also to `+0.5`.

```js
function roundToDecimal(number) {
    let num = {
        int: Math.floor(number),
        dec: number - Math.floor(number)
    };
    if (num.dec < 0.25) {
        return num.int;
    }  else if (num.dec < 0.75) {
        return num.int + 0.5;
    } else {
        return num.int + 1;
    }
}

console.log(roundToDecimal(14.40));
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the value by 2, then round it. afterwards divide through 2. With this you have raounded on x.50 and x.00.

```js
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = ((Math.round((Math.ceil(501/500))*3.60*4))/2).toFixed(2);
```

```html
<b>Result:</b> 
<div id="total"></div>
<br>
<b>Expected Result:</b>
14.50
<br>
<p>If the value after decimal equal or above .25 than it should round of .50. It means the result should be 14.50 and if the result 14.25 than it should be only 14.</p>
```

Comment: @Ivar - Yes you are right, I corrected it. I had a fault in it + question is not complete because the OP deleted previous his question it and creates a new one. But with the new one we have not all informations here. The price is the fee for 2 years.